# firebase deployment error:"error occured while parsing your function triggers"

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am having an error while deploying a function as "error occured while parsing your function triggers" and syntax error at the line `firestore.collection('orders').get()` as `syntax error: unexpected token '.'`. My node version is v8.11.3.
I tried the command to update my node version:
 `npm install -g firebase-tools@latest` but the error still remains the same. Can you help me out with this?
This is my code.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var firestore = admin.firestore();

exports.webhook = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    console.log("request.body.result.parameters: ", request.body.result.parameters);
    switch(request.body.result.action)
    {
        case'bookhotel':
            let params = request.body.result.parameters;

            firestore.collection('orders').add(params)
            .then((docRef) => {

                console.log("docRef: ", docRef);
                response.send({
                    speech:
                        `${params["name"]} your hotel booking request for ${params["room-type"]} room is forwarded for ${params["persons"]} persons,
                     we will contact you on ${params["email"]} soon.`

                });
                return;
            })
            .catch((e => {
                console.log("error:", e);
                response.send({
                    speech: "something went wrong when writing on database"
                });
            }))
        break;
        case'showbooking':
            firestore.collection('orders').get()
            .then((querySnapshot))=>{
                var orders=[];
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=>{orders.push(doc.data()) });

                var speech=`you have ${orders["length"]} orders \n`;

                orders.forEach((eachOrder,index)=>{
                    speech=`number ${index+1} is ${eachOrder["room-type"]} room for
                         ${eachOrder["persons"]} persons, ordered by ${eachOrder["name"]},
                         contact email is ${eachOrder["email"]}`
                    })
                    response.send({
                        speech:speech
                    });
                })
                .catch((err)=>{
                    console.log('error getting documents',err);

                    response.send({
                        speech: "something went wrong when reading from database"
                    })
                })
        break;

        default:
            response.send({
                speech:"no action matched in webhook"
            })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code into VS Code, and it gave me a different errors.

First, you need curly braces around your case blocks.  Instead of this:

```
switch (thing) {
    case 'option1':
        statement;
        statement;
        break:
}
```

It should be like this:

```
switch (thing) {
    case 'option1': {
        statement;
        statement;
        break:
    }
}
```

Note the curly braces surrounding the block of statements.

Also you have one too many parenthesis on this line:

```
.then((querySnapshot))=>{
```

It should be:

```
.then((querySnapshot)=>{
```

After that, the code compiles fine.